# How can I average every nth element in a Matrix in a vectorized way?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, mean

In Matlab, I have a 64x64x256x256 matrix A. I would like to average every 4th element of the last 2 dimensions to get a matrix that is 64^4. Previously I accomplished this using 2 for loops however, it was very slow and I would like speed it up.

```
for n2 = 1:pts
    tmp_Matrix(:,:,:,n2) = sum(Matrix_A(:,:,:,(1+numAvg*(n2-1):n2*numAvg)),4)/numAvg;
end
for n1 = 1:pts
    Final_Matrix(:,:,n1,:) = sum(tmp_Matrix(:,:,(1+numAvg*(n1-1):n1*numAvg),:),3)/numAvg;
end
```

There were some other similar questions but they were dealing with a 2 dimensional matrix and did not scale up to higher dimensions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code averages groups of N elements, not every Nth element. Did you preallocate the output arrays? Preallocation is key to making that loop fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) :

```
tmp_Matrix = movmean (                       ...
  Matrix_A,                                  ...
  [0 numAvg-1],                              ...
  4,                                         ...
  'Endpoints', 'discard',                    ...
  'SamplePoints', 1:numAvg:size(Matrix_A, 4) ...
);

Final_Matrix = movmean (                     ...
  tmp_Matrix,                                ...
  [0 numAvg-1],                              ...
  3,                                         ...
  'Endpoints', 'discard',                    ...
  'SamplePoints', 1:numAvg:size(Matrix_A, 3) ...
);
```